# Dockerfile not found while pushing docker image to GCP artifact registry using github actions

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, continuous-integration, github-actions

So I have been trying to build a docker image and push to the GCP artifact registry. I have written the following code snippet in the yml file.

```
      - name: 'Set up Cloud SDK'
        uses: 'google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v1'
        with:
          project_id: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_PROJECT }}
          service_account_keys: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}}
          export_default_credentials: true

      - name: Build docker image
        env:
          GCP_PROJECT_ID_PRODUCTION: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT }}
        run: |
          CI_COMMIT_BRANCH=${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}
          CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA=${GITHUB_SHA::8}
          docker build -t $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA .
```

After doing everything, I always come up with this error.

`ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount731432885/Dockerfile: no such file or directory`

I have my **Dockerfile** correctly named and with the same format without any extension in the root directory and my **github-ci.yml** file in the *.github/workflows* directory.

Is there a way to get it up and running. I am currently migrating my CI from Gitlab to Github actions and it worked perfectly fine in my Gitlab CI. I cannot find a way to build and push my docker images to the GCP artifact registry.

I have tried changing the **Dockefile** location from root to inside the workflows. It still throws the same error. I have tried all the stackoverflow answers and all of them either point out to place the Dockerfile in the root or naming it correctly. It seems to be fine in my case.

Comment: Please include the rest of your workflow in your question. Apparently, it looks like you're missing the checkout step.

Comment: You can use [`GITHUB_REF_NAME`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables) to get the branch name directly instead of trimming `GITHUB_REF`.

Comment: Yes, the checkout step is missing in your [workflow](https://github.com/samjain2907/hyuga-catalog-service-test/blob/main/.github/workflows/github-ci.yml).

Comment: See https://docs.docker.com/build/ci/github-actions/.

Comment: Thanks @Azeem. Surprisingly I was missing the checkout step.